# How do I make git block commits that do not include a certain file?

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit

I have one repo containing several directories which are essentially broken down into separate apps down the folder path, like this:

```
repo/foo/app1
        /app2
        /app3
    /bar/app1
        /app2
        /app3
    /red/app1
        /app2
        /app3
```

I now have a need to provide version info (metadata.rb) for app2. I want to configure git to block any commits for any app2 folder that does not include a change to app2/metadata.rb. I don't have root access to the repo, so I need to do this all locally. I know I can use a hook, but I don't know how to configure the hook. Thanks!

Comment: Enforcing this kind of thing on the git level might not be the best idea. Sending out an email to the team might work much better without polluting git repository with unnecessary restrictions.

Comment: You want to block commits touching any file in the app2 directory unless it also changes app2/metadata.rb? That doesn't make sense to me; why would a typo correction or a whitespace adjustment require a change to metadata.rb?

Comment: I don't mind doing this on the git level, because I will be the only one affected. For me, any change that is important enough to commit 'right now' **should** require a change to app2/metadata.rb. Typos are unlikely, and whitespace changes will never, spawn an immediate commit.

Comment: @DrStrangepork, as a side note: _Typos are unlikely, and whitespace changes will never, spawn an immediate commit._, one day you will regret mixing your typo/whitespace corrections with your real work.